# DateTimePicker in Windows Applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to retrieve the date user selected in the DateTimePicker in Windows Applications in my business logic code. How can I do that? plz help me.

Answer (score 3):

The business layer code should not directly access the UI. You could pass the selected value to it from the UI which is where the DatePicker control resides. You could use the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property to get or set this value.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpExpireDate.Value);
DateTime todayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
if (selectedDate < todayDate)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected date Must be greater then Today's date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimePicker.value
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx